# spinning down the hard drive with hdparm doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu

I want to spin down my hard-drive with hdparm in UBUNTU. I issue the standby signal with the following command:

```
sudo hdparm -S 1 /dev/sda?;sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda?
```

This should enforce a standby after 5 seconds and the next command should show all the drives in standby mode. Instead of this, I get the following output:

```
 /dev/sda1:
 setting standby to 1 (5 seconds)

/dev/sda2:
 setting standby to 1 (5 seconds)

/dev/sda5:
 setting standby to 1 (5 seconds)

/dev/sda1:
 drive state is:  active/idle

/dev/sda2:
 drive state is:  active/idle

/dev/sda5:
 drive state is:  active/idle
```

It means the drive is still active. How can I enforce the standby mode?

Comment: The `-S` option does not enforce standby at all. Other options may change the behavior of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't look at partitions, look at drives.
- Wait 5 seconds before reading the state.
- Standby isn't necessarily spun down -- sleep is.

Comment: sorry. I looked up at 5 seconds. It's fine now. Is there any way to measure the power consumption of the drive in active, standby and busy mode? I see no effect if I measure the overall system power with a power meter.

Comment: That's because modern hard drives simply don't draw much.  A 7200 RPM drive only draws about 1-2 watts at idle (while spinning, no seeking).  "Green" drives will draw slightly less, and if you're running high performance 10,000 RPM drives (or "Black"-series) you probably aren't using them in an environment where it makes sense to spin them down often.